# mysql multiple where and where not in

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql query that currently looks like this,

```
select * from `users`   
where `first_name` LIKE "%Martin%" 
or `last_name` LIKE "%Martin%"   
or `email` LIKE "%Martin%" 
and `users`.`id` not in  
(186,85,184,252,256,181)
```

I have user in my table with the first_name attribute being **Martin** and their ID being **181** yet there are being returned in the database, how come I am assuming there is some confusion in my mysql?

I wanting to return all users where the first_name, last_name or email are LIKE a string unless the users id matches an id an array?

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use parentheses:

```
select * 
from `users`   
where (`first_name` LIKE "%Martin%" or
       `last_name` LIKE "%Martin%" or  
       `email` LIKE "%Martin%" ) and
       `users`.`id` not in (186,85,184,252,256,181)
```

`AND` takes precedence over `OR`, hence the above query *without the parentheses* doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users`   
WHERE
  ( `first_name` LIKE "%Martin%" 
     OR `last_name` LIKE "%Martin%"   
     OR `email` LIKE "%Martin%" )
AND `users`.`id` NOT IN (186,85,184,252,256,181)
```