# MySQL select with all where and one or more where not

Tags: mysql

Table structure and data (I know data in IP/domain fields might not make much sense, but this is for illustration purposes):

```
rec_id | account_id | product_id | ip          | domain          | some_data
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1          | 1          | 192.168.1.1 | 127.0.0.1/test  | abc
2      | 1          | 1          | 192.168.1.1 | 127.0.0.1/other | xyz
3      | 1          | 1          | 192.168.1.2 | 127.0.0.1/test  | ooo
```

Table has unique index `ip_domain` combined from `ip` and `domain` fields (so records with identical values in both fields can't exist).

In each case I know values for `account_id, product_id, ip, domain` fields, and I need to get other rows that have the SAME `account_id, product_id` values and one (or both) of `ip, domain` values are DIFFERENT.

Example: I know that `account_id=1`, `product_id=1`, `ip=192.168.1.1`, `domain=127.0.0.1/test` (so it matches `rec_id` 1), I need to select records with IDs 2 and 3 (because record 2 has `different domain` and record 3 has `different ip`).

So, I used query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
account_id='1' AND product_id='1' AND ip!='192.168.1.1' AND domain!='127.0.0.1/test'
```

Of course, it returned 0 rows. Looked at [mysql multiple where and where not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385579/mysql-multiple-where-and-where-not-in) and wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
account_id='1' AND product_id='1' AND installation_ip NOT IN ('192.168.1.1') AND installation_domain NOT IN ('127.0.0.1/test')
```

My guess is that this query is identical (just formatted different way), so 0 rows again. Found some more examples too, but none worked in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but you're using the wrong logical operation

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   account_id='1' AND product_id='1' AND
        (ip != '192.168.1.1' OR domain != '127.0.0.1/test')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table
  Where ROWID <> myRowid
    And account_id = '1'
    And product_id = '1';
```

myRowid is the unique id given by your dbms to each record, in this case you need to retrieve it with your select statement and then pass it back when using this select. This will return all the rows with account_id = 1 and product_id = 1 except the one you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are not defined/or if you want list then you may be look at Group By clause. Also, you may look at [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Query would be something like:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, PRODUCT_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IP||'|'||DOMAIN, ','), COUNT(1)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID, PRODUCT_ID
```

P.S.: I dont have mysql installed hence the query syntax is not verified